# Cannot get ng-hide and ng-show to work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio

I'm working on my first Angular website and all is going well the first page. The second page should appear and replace the first when it meets the condition set with ng-show, the html code is below

```
<body ng-controller="gameController">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-hide="message == null">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <h2>
                        <img ng-src="{{headerSrc}}" style="width: 300px; height: 250px" />
                    </h2>

                    <h3>
                        {{ message }}
                    </h3>
                 .
                 .
                 .
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button id="startBttn" style="color:white;background-color:green;width:200px;height:45px" ng-click="startGame()">Start Game</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="message == null">
            <form name="frmPlayGame" validate class="form-inline">
```

When the startBttn is pressed it runs startGame which sets message to null in the function in my controller gameController.js -
        $scope.startGame = function () {
            $scope.message = "";
        }
I was expecting that when message is set to null that my first page would hide and the second would replace it but nothing happens, could someone please tell me why.

Comment: You're setting the message to ''. That's an empty string and not considered to be the same as null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting message to an empty string and then testing for null.

You need to test for an empty string:

```
<div ng-show="message != ''">
```

Or set message to null:

```
$scope.startGame = function () { $scope.message = null; }
```